# Send data from Socket with loop

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I'm using socket to send data between java and c++. I can send data from java in a loop without problems, but in the loop which is sending data from c++ to java I'm getting only the first message like the message that I send in the second message or all other  messages are not same like what I send. They looks like this "��Cdwdx" but what I sent is for example "hello" what is the error in my code?

This is my c++ code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
int sockfd; // socket file descriptor
int portno; // port number
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;
char rbuff[256];
int rbytes;
int choose;
std::string massage;
int main(){
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // generate file descriptor
    if (sockfd < 0)
        perror("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1"); //the ip address (or server name) of the listening server.
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(4447);

    while (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        puts("Waiting for connection\n");
        sleep(5);
    }
    puts("connected");
    std::cout << "Enter '1' for send to java \n Enter '2' for retrieve from java\n";
    std::cin >> choose;
    if (choose == 1){
        int wbytes;
        char * wbuff;
        while (true){
            std::cin >> (massage);
            wbuff =  (char *)massage.c_str();
            wbytes = write(sockfd, wbuff, strlen(wbuff));
            wbytes = write(sockfd, "\n", strlen(wbuff));
            if(wbytes < 0) perror("Cannot write to socket");
        }

    }else if (choose == 2){
        rbytes = recv(sockfd, rbuff, sizeof(rbuff), 0); // similar to read(), but return -1 if socket closed
        rbuff[rbytes] = '\0'; // set null terminal
        printf("Message: %s\n", rbuff);
    }

}
```

Comment: The only loop in this code calls `connect`, not `send` or `write`. What's stopping you from calling `write` in a loop?

Comment: i tried to send the write in loop but it dosent work that is why i showed this code to get a solution from a wroking code not a code with a loop wich dosent work

Comment: Show the code that "doesn't work", and explain in what way it doesn't work - what outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: ok i will edit now

Comment: done now you can check it

Comment: `write(sockfd, "\n", strlen(wbuff));` The string literal `"\n"` is likely shorter than `strlen(wbuff)` bytes. You transmit `\n` as well as whatever random garbage happens to be in memory after it.

Comment: i got it ,It works Thank you very much

Comment: `while (connect(...) < 0)` is wrong. If `connect()` fails and you want to retry, you must close the socket, create a new one, and call `connect()` on the new socket. Mere looping will never work, and will never cease.